# Calculating battery charging time

Tags: batteries, charging

I have a flashlight with 3.7V 6800mAh battery and a wall charger. The charger output is rated at 5.6V 0.7A.
According to my calculations:

Battery = 3.7 * 6.8 = 25.16 (Wh) ======
Charger = 5.6 * 0.7 = 3.92 (Wh)

25.16 / 3.92 = 6.4 hours

If we consider charger efficiency and losses (due to heat, etc), we can say it takes about **7 hours** to fully charge the above-mentioned battery.

**So, do you think it is safe to leave it plugged for 7 hours?**

Comment: We don't know what kind of charging circuitry your flashlight has, how long it will charge the battery, and whether it is safe to leave it plugged for any length of time.

Comment: Unit error in your calculation. V x A = W, not Wh. As for safe to leave it connected , any proper li-ion charger should cut off automatically and be able to be left plugged in forever.

Comment: Is the wall charger designed for that flashlight or battery or are you just taking a random "charger" and plugging that on the battery? Is it really a charger or just a transformer? Is there really a charging circuit somewhere (batteries usually need a more complex scheme switching between constant-current and constant-voltage), either in the flashlight or the "charger"? Is there a battery protection circuit?

Comment: @jcaron - No, it is not a random charger, I'm using the charger which came with it when I bought it. However, the charger has failed and it read zero voltage when I tested it with my digital voltmeter. I'm no electronic expert but I could see some electronic board inside the flashlight.

Comment: @jcaron - I'm going to choose another charger with the same V and A reading but I'm not sure if I should do it.

Comment: @NarimanAsgharian It depends a lot on whether it's actually a charger or just a transformer. Without any reference or pictures it's probably quite difficult to guess.

Comment: @jcaron - What picture do you need? A picture of the charger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, Li-Ion batteries are dangerous when improperly charged (or discharged, for that matter).

If you suspect that the device and the charger are not up to some acceptable standard and/or unsafe when left plugged in for any amount of time, don't use them - either dispose off them properly or find reliable information about the safety of this particular brand and model of flashlight.

Missing end-of-charge / full battery indicator is a bad sign.

Mishandled Li-Ion batteries explode spectacularily and are able to start hard to extinguish fires.

Second, your calculation have two obvious mistakes:

1. The battery holds energy measured in watt-hours, but the charger has power measured in watts. That's why you divide Watt-hours to watts and get hours. Other than that, your numbers add up... exept:
2. You grossly overestimate the efficiency of the charging circuit / process. Most of these charging circuits are linear regulators, so the proper calculation is something like:

6.8 Ampere-hours / 0.7 ampere = ~9.5 hours.

Other factors may prolong the full charging time by whatever factor, but my out of thin air estimate is 12-16 hours for a reliable full charge. For some meanings of "reliable".

---

p.s. in order to save the effort of the next users:

There is no such thing like 6.8Ah cell in 18650 size.

The best 18650 cells that are possible with the current technology are like 3.8-3.9Ah and such cells are rare, expensive and capricious.

Mass-produced good and sane cells are 1.5-3.0 Ah

Comment: The charger has a small lamp that Indicates full charge by turning from red to green. However, it is so strange that the green light appears only after 3 hours or so which is way sooner than what you and I calculated!

Comment: Ah, this is not strange at all. The battery has capacity way less than advertised, just like it is popular in this particular market segment. 6.8Ah looks like twice the best 18650 size cells that exist.

Comment: Could it be that the battery has lost its capacity over time?

Comment: Of course - e.g. after a year of heavy use? How much cells are there?

Comment: Only one cell. This is the battery: https://img.joomcdn.net/33ead0a3554d9dfa8d368e4eedfcbe3a63874180_original.jpeg

Comment: Ok, you should have started with this picture. This battery has capacity in the range of 1.2-1.8 Ah. And we still don't have the technology to make a 18650 size Li-Ion cell having more than ~3.8Ah capacity. And 3.8 cells are quite expensive, that's why 1.5-3.0Ah cells are used in general.

Comment: @NarimanAsgharian - FYI, as kindly commented by *fraxinus* above, the marked 6800 mAh capacity of such cells is fake. Not only is 6800 mAh about twice the best current 18650 cells, those cells with fake claims will be nowhere near that current best capacity. Tests on such fake cells reported a variety of *actual* capacities in the few hundreds of mAh or perhaps a little over 1000 mAh. See [here](http://danyk.cz/test18650_en.html) for one example of test results on some fake 18650 cells.

Comment: @SamGibson - I'm really shocked by the results!! Advertised 5800 mAh = Real 554 mAh!!! That's ridiculous! Interesting piece of information in your link!!

Comment: @fraxinus - It used to hold charge longer. I even used this flashlight to find my way in a dark cave outside the city! Now, I use it to illuminate my engine bay for timing belt replacement and other maintenance services in my car.

Comment: lots of sellers on ebay and other sites over there are selling 18650 batteries wrongly rated at 7000mAh and higher. Some of them are full of rice flour instead of battery chemicals.